# Why use EXPOSE in Dockerfile -- since you can bind to all ports anyways

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ports

I can `docker run -p 3000:3000 image` *without* `EXPOSE`ing that port in the container (see below). If that's true, then why bother putting EXPOSE in the Dockerfile? Is it just for communication to image users? Because I don't know of a functional reason to EXPOSE ports if they are all bindable anyways.

---

Here are the steps showing me binding to a port in a container despite the fact it is not EXPOSEd

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine
RUN apk add nodejs npm vim
COPY webserver /webserver
CMD [ "node", "/webserver/index.js" ]


$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.931MB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine
 ---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/4 : RUN apk add nodejs npm vim
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4270f8bdb201
Step 3/4 : COPY webserver /webserver
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67f4cda61ff0
Step 4/4 : CMD [ "node", "/webserver/index.js" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1df8f9024b85
Successfully built 1df8f9024b85


$ curl localhost:4400
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4400: Connection refused


$ docker run -d -p 4400:3000 1df8f9024b85
7d0e6c56f8ad8827fe72830a30c1aac96821104b8ea111291ca39e6536aad8fd


$ curl localhost:4400
Hello World!


$
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Docker's [EXPOSE documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) addresses this specific point:

> The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the `-p` flag on `docker run` to publish and map
>   one or more ports, or the `-P` flag to publish all exposed ports and
>   map them to high-order ports.

Pay attention to the last sentence, if you expose multiple ports then `-P` becomes useful to avoid setting multiple `-p` on the command line.

Comment: The "documentation" is in the form of image metadata. In addition to being useful to the `-P` flag, other utilities can query the running containers for this metadata, which is useful in proxies that dynamically update their forwarding rules using these exposed ports as their defaults.

Comment: @BMitch absolutely, I felt it was an extraneous information not yet useful for the OP, but feel free to edit it in.

Comment: EXPOSE is documentation

Answer (score 5):

This is done for automation sake. You can have a universal command that runs `docker run -P` to start a container and the Dockerfile itself is used to specify which container exposes which port. In case you are dealing with dozens or hundreds of containers being built through a pipeline, this is quite useful. Passing external details not contained in Dockerfile together with the container through pipeline from stage to stage is quite difficult at scale.